# Product Cluster based on title Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, aggregate

I am building a Price Aggregator with fetches information from 20 online stores and to present a comparision. Each store has differtn product title format e.g
iPhone 6
iPhone6 64gb black
iPhone6 32gb
iPhone gold - 64gb

Currently I am manually grouping the products to present a comparision. How can I make grouping of same products automatic ?

Comment: don't use their titles, instead extract the technical specs from the stores and use those

Comment: its a nice suggestion, will explore it further. However, we would prefer an alternate option to comparing specifications.

Comment: You'll always be inferior when relying on lossily compressed data like titles instead of fact sheets... how do you compare *iPhone 6* with *iPhone 6 32gb gold*? You cannot, you're missing information and comparing potentially two very different products. Any such comparison is useless.